# MySQL - Get first 3 comma separated values

Tags: mysql, string

I have a query which returns a field with a set of comma separated values.  I would like to get the first three of these values into separate columns in the query result.

I can get the first, using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but how can I get the other two?

```
SELECT 
  'aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc', ',', 1) AS column_one
```

EDIT - Oops, sorry forgot to mention.  The value I want to split could have more (or less) than three strings to extract.

For example, the above string could easily be 'aaaaa' or 'aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc, ddddd, eeeee'.

In each case, I only need the first three (or however many exist).

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) twice, the second one with -1 parameter:

```
SELECT
  'aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc', ',', 1) AS column_one,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc', ',', 2), ',', -1) AS column_two,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc', ',', 3), ',', -1) AS column_three
```

If the parameter is negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting from the right) is returned. Eg.

- `SUBSTRING_INDEX('aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc', ',', 2)` will return `aaaaa, bbbbb`
- `SUBSTRING_INDEX(`aaaaa, bbbbb`, ',', -1)` will then return `bbbbb`

You also might want to use ', ' as a delimiter, or [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) the result.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9654).

**Edit**

If you want to consider strings that might have less than three values, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
  s,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, ',', 1) AS column_one,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s)-LENGTH(Replace(s, ',', ''))>0
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, ',', 2), ',', -1)
       ELSE NULL END AS column_two,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(s)-LENGTH(Replace(s, ',', ''))>1
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s, ',', 3), ',', -1)
       ELSE NULL END AS column_three
FROM
  strings
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e054/1).