# SQL Server 2016 : get first 3 comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Is there a way in SQL Server 2016 to get what MySQl does with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`?  [MySQL - Get first 3 comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654309/mysql-get-first-3-comma-separated-values).  In one field I have the names of the authors of the publication.

```
Column1
--------------------------------------------
Herbst-Kralovetz MM, Quayle AJ, Ficarra M, Greene S, Rose WA, Chesson 
Radtke AL, Crabbé A, Sarker SF, Herbst-Kralovetz MM, Ott
```

I want to do something like this

```
Select FirstThreeFunction(Column1) 
From Table
```

And get this as result:

```
Herbst-Kralovetz MM, Quayle AJ, Ficarra M.
Radtke AL, Crabbé A, Sarker SF
```

Sometimes there are hundreds of names. What I would like to in a Select statement if pull the first three. I know that I can create a function and pass in all of the names then split them and join back the first three but is that the better way in SQL so I can add an Et al. to the names ?

I can get the first name using

```
SELECT 
    LEFT (Authors, CHARINDEX(',', Authors))
```

But can't figure how to add the distance for the third comma

Answer (score 2):

you can use `cte` to get these values. `f1` is the column

```
declare @n int
set @n = 3;

;with Tmp  as (
    select 1 as rn, charindex(',', f1) pos, f1 as st from test
    union all
    select rn + 1, charindex(',', st, pos + 1), st
    from Tmp
    where rn < @n
)select rn, substring(st, 1, pos-1) from Tmp where rn = 3
```

Comment: This in an interesting answer, but how would it be used against all columns in a table?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on SQL Server 2016 you can use the functions `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG`, together with a user defined function to accomplish what you want.

**EDIT:** I do apologize, the `STRING_AGG` function is not in SQL Server 2016, as @user1314159 points out, it was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

Let us start with the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_AggregateFromSplit(@column nvarchar(50), @sep char(1), 
@numberToReturn int)
RETURNS nvarchar(256)
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @retVal nvarchar(256);

  WITH cte
  AS
  (
    SELECT TOP(@numberToReturn) Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@column, @sep)
  )

  SELECT @retVal = (SELECT TOP(1) STRING_AGG(cte.Value, @sep)
  FROM cte)

  RETURN @retVal

 END
```

In the code above we create a user defined function which takes three parameters:

- A column name
- A separator character
- A value of how many to return

In the function code we use a `CTE` together with the `STRING_SPLIT` function to get a rowset of the split names, which we then pass to the `STRING_AGG` function to aggregate, which we return.

You would use it something like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(id int, name nvarchar(256))
INSERT INTO #t VALUES (1, 'Herbst-Kralovetz MM, Quayle AJ, Ficarra M, Greene S, Rose WA, Chesson'),
(2, 'Radtke AL, Crabbé A, Sarker SF, Herbst-Kralovetz MM, Ott')

SELECT func.names 
FROM #t t
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT dbo.fn_AggregateFromSplit(t.name, ',', 3) as names
) as func
GO
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really love this answer but it seems that STRING_AGG is not available in 2016

Answer (score 1):

```
select substring(Column1, 1, charindex(",", Column1, (charindex(",", Column1, (charindex(",", Column1, 1) + 1)) + 1)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first three comma separated values as given below. Read on [STRING_SPLIT](https://passreset.intel.com/VPNAccountReset.aspx).

**Caveat**: the below method will not work, if there are duplicate entries in the Comma separated list.

```sql
DECLARE @Column1 VARCHAR(2000) = 'Herbst-Kralovetz MM, Quayle AJ, Ficarra M, Greene S, Rose WA, Chesson '

--Till SQL Server 2016
SELECT STUFF((select concat(',',value) from
(SELECT Row_Number() OVER (order by (CHARIndex(value,@Column1,0))) as rownum,
value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Column1, ',') ) as t
WHERE rownum <=3
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

--From SQL Server 2017 onwards
select STRING_AGG(value, ',') from
(SELECT Row_Number() OVER (order by (CHARIndex(value,@Column1,0))) as rownum,
value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Column1, ',') ) as t
WHERE rownum <=3
```

Comment: There is no guarantee (as far as I know) that this returns the first three values.  If you can refer to documentation that does specify that the ordering for `string_split()` is guaranteed when using `order by (select 1))`, I would appreciate learning about it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I agree. Sorry that I overlooked this information. I have updated the query for comma separated list, if there are no duplicates in the list. I will try to come with another solution, in case of duplicates in the list.