# string cut after a character in mysql

Tags: mysql, string

Table 1

```
| string 1                               | 
|Zürich, Grüngasse                       | 
|Flagshipstore Thun, Bälliz, Raum 1      |
```

The above string needs to be cut into two columns with the string value that appears before the common (,)

Result

```
| col 1    | col2           |
| Zürich   | Grüngasse      |
|Thun      | Bälliz         |
```

Comment: Please add more sample data covering all edge cases

Comment: there are specific edge cases, other than that in a few cases like shown above there might be two commas and in the other case it's one.

Comment: So what is the reason for dropping the existance of `Flagshipstore` in `Flagshipstore Thun,`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate a column with comma you can use below approach, based on your expected result:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ',', 1) as first_column, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ',', 2), ',', -1) as second_column
from table_a;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/23
[image]

*Updated*: If you want to check strings that might have less than three values as @Akina mentioned in the comments use:

**Credits to user @fthiella:** [MySQL - Get first 3 comma separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654309/mysql-get-first-3-comma-separated-values)

```
 SELECT column1 as tot_column, SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ',', 1) AS first_col,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(column1)-LENGTH(Replace(column1, ',', ''))>0
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ',', 2), ',', -1)
       ELSE NULL END AS second_col,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(column1)-LENGTH(Replace(column1, ',', ''))>1
       THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ',', 3), ',', -1)
       ELSE NULL END AS third_col
FROM
  table_a
```

Comment: You must check the amount of delimiters. For example, if CSV value contains only 2 separate values then the last one will be received as both 2nd and 3rd which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: You may use more complex, but universal code. Test the amount of delimiters in 3rd parameter of inner SUBSTRING_INDEX. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50b6ab975dd34ebffec67a2986ea2f7c

Comment: *I will never store data separated by comma. I think the best solution is changing the table design* Agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want the string before the first comma and the rest of the column seperated into 2 parts

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ',', 1) as first_column, 
SUBSTRING(column1 FROM LOCATE(',', column1)) as the_rest 
from test;
```

[DEMO DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/21)

RESULT

```
| first_column       | the_rest           |
| ------------------ | ------------------ |
| Zürich             | , Grüngasse        |
| London             | ,, Paris, New York |
| Flagshipstore Thun | , Bälliz, Raum 1   |
```